# Vanishing of Cohomology of Affine Schemes -- Proof

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation, sheaf-cohomology, affine-schemes

I was following Ravi Vakil notes FOAG (http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf)
and I cannot understand **Th.18.2.4**, at least not all of it.

What I can follow is the first part: you extent the Cech complex, add $\textrm{Spec}(R) = U_0$ to your open cover, make a clever short exact sequence of complexes, and the long exact sequence in cohomology does the rest.

After this particular case, he want to show that the extended Cech complex is still exact even if $\textrm{Spec}(R)$ is not one of the open sets of the covering. And this general case I cannot understand.

I see the main idea is to show that we can reduce to the particular case, but I will be grateful if someone can break this down into pieces.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I directly refer to your link for notations. The idea is to work locally: since the scheme is affine, local means looking at the complex localised at some element (cf. how he points out that the complex of $A$-modules is actually a complex of $R$-modules). So now you have a lot of complexes (one for each $f_i$) which, by construction, belong to the base case and are exact. Therefore the global complex is also exact (exactness is checked locally). Does it make more sense?

Comment: Hi @Cla , sorry for the super late response! Yes, it made sense with your explanation. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help :)